# Windows 8 not connected to domain network

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2008-r2, mapping

We have several Windows XP and Windows 7 PCs connecting to Windows server 08. Each user has designated mapped drive according to their groups. Recently when we moved to Windows 8, the network drive doesn't appear.

What needs to be changed in Windows Server 08 group policy so that Windows 8 PC can automatically map network drives as in win xp or win7 pc?

Comment: Exactly how are you currently mapping the XP and 7 machines?

Comment: we use group policy to map drives for different user

Comment: That's what I'm trying to clarify... :) _How_ do you use GP to map the drives? Scripts? GPP?

Comment: we use GPP to map drives

Comment: Perhaps the GPP's set to target only certain operating systems?  Have you installed all your updates (specifically http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2795944)?

Comment: What domain functionality you running as? Are you getting errors about the GPP?